# Using onSaveInstanceState with fragments in backstack?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have fragments I keep in the backstack of FragmentManager. Every fragment state is saved for orientation changes with member variables, like this for example:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) 
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putLong("userId", mUserId);
    outState.putString("username", mUsername);
}
```

My problem is that if there is an orientation change, since every fragment in the backstack gets called via onSaveInstanceState, I get a null pointer exception because the member variables don't exist anymore.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: can you provide your logcat error message?

Comment: onSaveInstanceState gets called before the actual change is applied, so your variables should exist when you call them, unless they're null because of other bugs in your code. Post some more code along with the error output form Logcat.

Comment: I can assure you my variables are fine. I think the problem is that my fragments in the backstack aren't getting onSaveInstanceState called when they are torn down; onSaveInstanceState is only called when the activity is destroyed, yet my variables don't exist anymore. So my current solution to that is: "if (mUserId != null && mUsername != null) ...". It ain't pretty, but it solves the problem. I find it weird to have an onSaveInstanceState method for fragments if it's not called when the fragment is torn down.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It is possible that your member variables don't exist anymore because the `FragmentManager` in your `Activity` is dying with all of your fragments.

You need to override the method `onSaveInstanceState` of your `Activity` class as well, because you need to save the `Activity` state before you save the `Fragments` state.

As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) says:

> There are many situations where a fragment may be mostly torn down (such as when placed on the back stack with no UI showing), but its state will not be saved until its owning activity actually needs to save its state.

**UPDATE**

In your `Activity` `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`, try saving you `Fragment` references and then restore them with something like this:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    getFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "myfragment", myfragment);
}
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle inState){
    myFragment = getFragmentManager().getFragment(inState, "myfragment");
}
```

Tell me then if you had luck! :-)

Comment: Then what should I do? Should I call the fragment's onSaveInstanceState from the activity's onSaveInstanceState?

Comment: An UPDATE for you in the answer.

Comment: ok...so onSaveInstanceState for fragments is pretty much worthless. At least, for fragments (fragment transactions) that are in the back stack.

Comment: Yes, in fact, I think you can quit `onSaveInstanceState` for the nature of your case.

Comment: @Jorge Gil If you hit home button from a fragment and after some time when you try to open how can we regain same state. If the OS called GC in between.

Answer (score 7):

Building on Jorge Gil - 'xɔɾ.xɛ xil answer 
Note the following:

- Don't forget call the super implementations of onSaveInstanceState()
  and onRestoreInstanceState().
- If you are using the support package: Please use getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager().
- When retrieving your original fragment you got to cast it.

Sorry for being Captain obvious!

Answer (score 1):

Does setting the setRetainInstance on the fragment help.
try out

Comment: If fragment is used for UI purpose then never `setRetainInstance` to `true`!

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper solution is to read those member variables out of `savedInstanceState` in `onCreate` which seems to be called always before `onSaveInstanceState`. If you process the fields in `onViewCreated`, they don't have the chance to get initialized before the next `onSaveInstanceState` (in this special case, when Fragment is in the backstack).