# Fragment state lost when device left idle

Tags: android, android-fragments

Fragment losing state and shows an empty UI if left idle for 20 minutes. I'm using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and I have tried calling the `notifyDataSetChanged` in `onStart()` of my FragmentActivity.

Kindly help me how to save the object and state of my fragment and reuse it on reload of the app.

Answer (score 3):

Android can kill your app if needed, you need to use [`onSaveInstanceState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) to keep your state in this cases. (Remember: Save important data in [`onPause`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29)!)

[`onSaveInstanceState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) exists in Activity and Fragments and is used in the same way like an activity

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("integer", anInteger);
}
```

Now in [`onCreate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29), [`onCreateView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView%28android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle%29) or [`onActivityCreated`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated%28android.os.Bundle%29) you have this argument [`Bundle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)`savedInstanceState` which corrisponds to the bundle saved. (Check if it's null too.)

---

If not enought maybe Android killed your [`FragmentManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) too, so you need to override [`onSaveInstanceState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and [`onRetoreInstanceState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) in your Activity and restore the fragment.

Maybe this answer could help you about the last thing i said: [Using onSaveInstanceState with fragments in backstack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608709/using-onsaveinstancestate-with-fragments-in-backstack)

Comment: +1 for an answer with more explanation than mine. You should just add the example of how to check onSaveInstanceState != null

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without your code.

However I can say that the state is usually saved by the `savedInstanceState`

Usually in the `onActivityCreated` you have something like the following. In the example I give I save a boolean of either text was entered or not.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mHasText = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(HAS_TEXT_TAG);
    } else {
       // do something
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(HAS_TEXT_TAG, mHasText);
}
```

it's just an example as without your code it's difficult to anwer

Answer (score 0):

A `Fragment`'s life-cycle is closely tied to the `Activity`'s lifecycle. This means, when your `Activity` goes idle; it will kill off any contained `Fragments`. To store `Fragments` you could always retain them in concordance with the [Fragment API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html). This means you will generally be using the Fragment in a background. However the best way to keep a from being destroyed or lost from an `Activity`'s end would be to store relevant information in a custom object and then to recreate the `Fragment` when the `Activity` is resumed.

For instance; I could have a custom object that would store relevent UI values for my `Fragment` and when my `Activity` either idles or changes I would save those relevant values to my custom object that I created. Then, when either a new `Activity` is created; or my old `Activity` is resumed; I would retrieve those values and put them back into my `Fragment`'s UI. Hoped this helped :)

Comment: As I mentioned in my question I'm already calling the notifydatasetchanged of the view pager adapter in the onStart method of my fragment activity but unfortunately it hasn't solved my problem. I designed the adapter so that it doesn't recreate the fragment object whenever the notifydatasetchanged is called but uses the earlier object. Do you think i should also call the refresh ui method on my fragment??

Answer (score 0):

In case android needs memory, it kills the running apps. So you must save the objects using

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {}
```

Note that savedState must be serializable.

You must call notifyDataSetChanged() in onResume(), because it  ensures that it is called when the activity resumes.

For a detailed answer, please post your code.