# Android losing state when screen is OFF and ON again

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-savedstate

I'm struggling with an issue regards `Activity > ViewPager > Fragments` that are being totally destroyed and recreated again, i'm handling this kind of scenario like when the screen `orientation` changed i just `restore` my `data` from the saved `instance`, however when my device go idle for awhile and screen goes `off` and `ON` again, the saved `data` inside the `instance` is being `destroyed` and its null.
code example:

> Base Fragment

```
@Override public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Icepick.saveInstanceState(this, outState);
}

 @Override public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Icepick.restoreInstanceState(this, savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}
```

> Activity

```
    mAdapter = new BrochureContentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), models);
    pager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    pager.setCurrentItem(position, true);
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(models.size());
```

the  `BaseFragment` handle saving and restoring `instance` via `IcePick` when the screen rotates (recreated) everything goes well, my only issue is that within the `fragment` that extends the `BaseFragment` if the screen go `idle` for awhile and `ON` back, the saved instances are being totally destroyed.

anyone had similar issue before and find a way of tackling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what really solved the issue for me was just moving stuff around for instance

`Icepick.restoreInstanceState(this, savedInstanceState);`

was inside of `onActivityCreated` which it was being called every time i come from screen `OFF` somehow my `bundle` data are being cleared and to solve that issue my `saving/restoring` order become as below:

```
@Override public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Icepick.saveInstanceState(this, outState);
}

@Override public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null && !savedInstanceState.isEmpty()) {
        Icepick.restoreInstanceState(this, savedInstanceState);
    }
}

@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}
```

moving `Icepick.restoreInstanceState(this, savedInstanceState);` from `onActivityCreated` to `onViewCreated` and `setRetainInstance` from `onActivityCreated` to `onCreate` solved the issue.
i hope it help someone in the future.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out, but restore your state in OnCreate, not in onViewCreated, onViewCreated is called every time your fragment's view is destroyed which is usually from a FragmentTransaction.

Comment: @Tunji_D but as you mentioned onCreate wont be called, then how in earth the states are going to be restored? would you mind explaining more? as i really wanna hear more about it

Comment: In the fragment lifecycle, onCreate is called only when the Fragment is being created for the first time, or being restored from a saved state. If onCreate is not called, you do not have any state to check for / restore.

onViewCreated is always called when returning to a Fragment after it's view was destroyed, this is usually because the Fragment was added to the backStack, but it's also called if you're restoring it from a saved state because the view was also destroyed then.

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle

Note, while the docs say you can restore state in onCreate, onCreateView, or afterActivityCreated, I had issues with the support library if I didn't restore in onCreate. 

Typically, restore state in onCreate, and then access restored state in onViewCreated or OnActivity created.

Comment: hmm, i always find it difficult to follow the docs to be honest they don't give any good info, must of it out dated and not true must of the time, i will try that, however i still doubt that, but lets see. i will reply later with the result. thanks Tunji for your continuos help.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your activity is destroying the instance of the FragmentManager, which means that your Fragment (along with it's data in savedInstanceState) could be getting destroyed.
See this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22914015/1738090

Have you tried additionally restoring the fragment from your Activity in `onStart()` or `onResume()` to see if that works?

Comment: i'm not adding any fragments within the activity, it just a viewpager as i showed in the activity section in my question.

Comment: What is it that you're doing in `new BrochureContentAdapter()` where you're passing off a reference of `getSupportFragmentManager()`? I'm not familiar with the IcePick library, so if there's a problem there, I'm afraid I won't be of much help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your fragment isn't fully being destroyed, only it's view is. Check if `onDestroyView` was called for the fragment, and if it was, restore your View state in `OnActivityCreated`.

Comment: the views will always be destroyed but whatever you save in the onSaveInstance should not!. thats the scenario of recreating the activity. and as you can see i'm restoring the saved states within onActivityCreated.

Comment: Oh, I see now. OnActivityCreated is always called regardless of if onSaveInstanceState is called or not, so when you resume your activity, you're restoring state from a null bundle. That is, onSaveInstanceState wasn't called, your state still existed, but you overwrote it with data from a null bundle.

You should check if the bundle is non null in onActivityCreated first before you use IcePick to restore state.

Comment: well i guess that make sense, im trying it now tho, i will get back to you asap.

Comment: nope, that did not help, im still getting null pointer exception  in onViewCreated.

Comment: Well i guess i did find a way, at least for the past few mintuted testing everything was okay, will keep testing and if it actually solve it i will post the answer