# onSaveInstanceState of previous fragment is called on-orientation of current fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

### **What i am doing** ::

- I load a fragment(`eg:: Fragment-A`) to the container, and in
  `onSaveInstanceState` event i am storing some data into bundle

***i use the code***

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putInt("yourSpinner", spnSearchByCity.getSelectedItemPosition());

    }
```

- Now i `replace` the `container` with `Fragment-B` on click of button
  in `Fragment-A`

***i use the code***

```
fragment = FrgMdMap.newInstance(messengerObj);

                    if (fragment != null) {
                        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    }
```

- I am successfully able to load the `Fragment-B`
- Now on orientation change of Fragment-B the `onSaveInstanceState` of
  `Fragment-A` id firing

---

### **Questions**::

- How is this taking place ?
- How can i make sure this wont happen ?

Comment: Take a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608709/using-onsaveinstancestate-with-fragments-in-backstack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
How is this taking place ?
```

Actually `Fragment-A` is still alive and well underneath your `Fragment-B` that is due to the `addToBackStack(null)` added when you replaced the fragment.

```
How can i make sure this wont happen ?
```

You can remove the `addToBackStack(null)` or count the number of stacked fragments in your `onSaveInstanceState` method and when it is 0 then you can run the code inside your `onSaveInstanceState`

**EDIT:**

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0)
    outState.putInt("yourSpinner", spnSearchByCity.getSelectedItemPosition());

}
```

Comment: [+1] for info .... on Quote"count the number of stacked fragments in your onSaveInstanceState method and when it is 0 then you can run the code inside your onSaveInstanceState" ...... Can you show me an example  on your answer !

Comment: @Devrath first thing first are you only using the addtobackstack in your FragmentB

Comment: i am using addtobackstack in your FragmentA ... Not in B .... also i removed addToBackStack(null) in fragmentA ...still it is throwing same scenario(it might be holding any other thing in backstack ? possibly ?) ..... i was not able to understand  " count the number of stacked fragments in your onSaveInstanceState method and when it is 0 then you can run the code inside your onSaveInstanceState" in the answer

Comment: @ Rod_Algonquin .... I was able to resolve it thanks, but i want to ask ..... does the control always goes to previous fragment onsaveinstancestate when we rotate the device when we are in current fragment ?