# Distinguish first vs followings onCreateView's call in fragment

Tags: android, fragment-lifecycle

Probably it is a well-known topic, but I didn't find any "universal" solution.

The main problems are two:

- When a `fragment` is put to `backstack`, `onSavedInstanceState` is never called
- Why can't you instantiate `fragment's` views in `onCreate`?

And at this point my question is: since the `fragment lifecycle` goes through `onCreateView` every `resume`, and since we can't instantiate `views` in `onCreate`; why do we have to re-create `views` every time the `fragment` is shown? There must be a way as in the `Activity` with `onCreate`.

We might avoid by adding a `class-scoped boolean` and check if it has a value, but it means adding an `if` and this can't be the best solution. Another solution might be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17135346/4700782), but it is also a workaround and it also has some limitations.

Is there a built-in (or a standard) solution that solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unclear on the meaning of the title of your question - but I can answer these three points:

> When a fragment is put to backstack, onSavedInstanceState is never called

`onSavedInstanceState` is called when saving state - just adding to the backstack is not causing that to happen - it happens when pausing the fragment if there is some UI showing. Actually a good answer addressing this problem exists [here (link)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15914053/984830)

> Why can't you instantiate fragment's views in onCreate?

A fragment is resumed from the `onPostResume` method of an Activity, only at this point can you safely touch the views of a fragment. (Inside the fragment you can use `onViewsCreated`)

> why do we have to re-create views every time the fragment is shown

This can be avoided by retaining your fragment instances (although there are [drawbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11318942/984830)). You can retain by using:

```
setRetainInstance(true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have just a couple of questions: afaik, using onSavedInstanceState of the activity has some problems when using a ViewPager, is it right? the second one is that Retain is a good option but it has, as you pointed out, a couple of problems (first of all, the performance one). But if those are the only options, I don't really have many possibilities :)

Comment: Well, what is your aim? Just to know if it is the first time a particular fragment is shown? For that your `class-scoped boolean` is definitely the cleanest approach. If not, instead of getting a complete instance state from the fragment your activity could store the value from the fragment inside it's own state (including restoring the variable (not the views) when restored

Comment: Ok, thanks! yeah I would like to know if it is the first time, so I can avoid calling `view.findViewById(...)` every time I pop the fragment.